# Why does Devaki forego Salvation?

Tags: krishna, moksha

According to this YouTUBE video, Lord Krishna appears to Devaki and Vasudeva in Evil Kansa's prison.

[Lord Krishna visits Devaki and Vasudeva in Evil Kansa's Prison](https://youtu.be/Xp061xsX6j0?t=26m19s)

Lord Krishna tells Devaki how to get salvation, but Devaki says she doesn't wish for salvation. Instead, she wishes to have mother-son relationship with Lord Krishna (who is really incarnation of Lord Vishnu).

According to Scriptures, why would anyone want to forgo salvation? This is new to me.

Comment: Everyone talks about salvation. But actually very few want it.. Only those who know the misery of Samsara wants to be free from cycles of birth and death... for us we are enjoying this life itself... although there is misery but still we want this life... for eg.. if Lord Vishnu himself came to a person in earth and tells I eill take you to Vaikuntha... I am sure he wouldn't go with Lord Vishnu.. he Will start thinking about his family and various earthly attachment... and will finally began to ask ... "Can't I go latter I have to do this this?"... I'll come laater... I won't go... etc.. etc..

Comment: Apply it for yourself.. suppose that Lord Vishnu came to you just you are reading this comment and tells "Lets go to Vaikuntha, I'll give salvation to you." Do you really think you will go with him. No... I'm sure you wouldn't go... Various earthly attachment would made you reject that offer... You would think your parents would be worried about your sudden disappearance.. you will think about various attachments of earths like husband, child, lovers (if have).. and finally you will ask "Can't I come latter"?...Thus only those want salvation who truly knows and experiences misery of samsara..

Comment: @Tezz Not only normal men attached to samsara but even **great saints** like the Azhvars have refused Moksha in their poems saying all they want is to sing about the Lord and enjoy his pastimes, and not reside in Vaikuntha where he is always in Shayana. Devaki falls into the category of the **great saint** who wanted to enjoy being God's mother.

Comment: @Surya well, I think it's the same... They want to serve feet of Lord and enjoy past times of Lord because they get happiness from that.. ie. They do not experience misery of Samsara by that act (as they get satisfied and happy in serving)... So, as they do not experience misery of Samsara so they do not want Salvation... My main point is not about normal man attached to Samsara... but the question is whether they experience misery of Samsara or not... whether they are satisfied with earthly life or not... and if they are satisfied why would they want other things like salvation...

Comment: @Tezz Oh you meant that way. Sorry, the comments you posted pointed more towards an ignorant man who doesn't want to give up his attachments, so I didn't take the corollary.

Comment: @Surya - One way why devaki didn't want moksha is that it is the divine play of the Lord. I heard in a pravachan that Prishni  and Sutapa worshipped Lord Vishnu for Moksha, but the moment Lord appeared before them they just wanted him as their son for three births. So, it is play of the Lord. Ultimately, devaki and vasudeva did get moksha.

Comment: @Krishna Yes divine play is definitely there, even Bhagavatam says that. But, I think, _given a choice_ Devaki would have definitely chosen to be his mother, rather than Moksha.

Comment: @Surya - It is by their choose too, to be the parents of Lord. In fact, they wanted moksha, but on seeing Lord she wanted to be his mother